# json.loads() is returning a string?

Tags: python, json

So I am trying to download a json from s3. When it is downloaded it is a string. I then try to convert it to a json using json.loads() but it is returning a string. How do I fix this?

```py
s3_json_file = client_s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=f'player_jsons/{name}_info.json')['Body'].read()
            json_str = s3_json_file.decode('utf-8').strip()
            json_obj = json.loads(json_str)
            print(type(json_str))
            print(type(json_obj))
```

Comment: What's the contents of the file? What is the output of the script? Add all details to the question

Comment: It would help to show the contents of `json_obj` and `json_str`.

Comment: If your JSON represents a string this is normal, and the question doesn't have enough details to rule out this possibility.

Comment: There's a common, and mistaken, assumption that all JSON values are objects. That's not true, though they are far and away the most common type of JSON value returned by, say, an API. `json.loads('"foo"')`, for example, returns a `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it turns out I forgot to change the name of the file I was downloading so it was downloading an empty test file which was causing the problem.